# Oracle sync data from two tables on string column

Tags: oracle, join, insert, bulkinsert

I have two tables of addresses like: A1 with Street,City,Building and other one A2 with this three columns and others. The tables don't have the same structure and A1 doesn't have a primary key and i can't add one because is not in my database.

So, i want to insert all data from A1 which are not in A2, comparing the STREET,CITY and BUILDING columns.

How can i do this because the comparison on the string columns is very slow in oracle.I notice that i have a lot of data .
Can i do this somehow using batch and bulkinsert?

Thank you

Comment: Insert data in A2? If  yes that what should be the values of other columns? Null?

Comment: Yes, i want to insert the data into A2

Comment: Not understanding something - if the problem is that string comparison is very slow in Oracle, how would batch and bulkinsert help? How do they speed up string comparisons?

Comment: maybe if i do something in parallel, that was because i asked for batch

Comment: If you don't have an index, then probably doing a full table scan.  What does explain plan show?  If you don't have the proper keys/indexes on the table, then you cannot expect efficiency.

Comment: i have indexes on all these three column

Answer (score 0):

Update: Try merge, which basically do the same thing. Also see if you can create index on the columns in join condition, which would improve performance.

```
MERGE INTO A2
    USING A1
    ON (a1.street=a2.street and a1.city=a2.city and a1.building=a2.building)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (Street,City,Building)
    VALUES (a1.Street,a1.City,a1.Building);
```

Previous:

```
 insert into A2 (Street,City,Building)
 select a1.Street,a1.City,a1.Building 
 from a1 left join a2 
 on a1.street=a2.street and a1.city=a2.city and a1.building=a2.building
 where a2.street is null and a2.city is null and a2.building is null
```